# AJAX/PHP/Jquery Issue with callback

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback

I can't seem to figure out why this won't work.  I have stripped all elements out and have striped this done to a base example.  can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.  When I click on the button on the html page I get my initial alert, but never get an alert from my call backs.

Here is the code for my html file.  test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#test").click(function()
{
    alert("!st");
    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',

        url : 'test_ajax.php',

        dataType : 'json',

        data: {

        email : 'Jeremy'

        },

        success : function(data){

            alert(data.msg);

        },

        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }

    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="test" id="test" type="button" value="Click Me"/>
<div id="results">
  Hello
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now for the php: test_ajax.php

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {

    $return['error'] = true;

    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you email.';

}

else {

    $return['error'] = false;

    $return['msg'] = 'You\'ve entered: ' . $_POST['email'] . '.';

 }


 echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Please any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Jeremy

Comment: You may figure out any problem with AJAX request using Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Can you post the response JSON?

Comment: Can we see the JSON response? I'm sure you do, but just making sure you have a starting `<?php` tag in your php file.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks clean. Try to use php [buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). Put `ob_start()` at the very beginning of PHP file and in the code

```
// cleans the buffer
ob_clean();    
echo json_encode($return);
die();
```

Comment: I tried adding the ob_start and the ob_clean.  Still no results from the call backs.

Comment: please use this Firefox+Firebug or give us URL to check the request.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the exact code and it works ok.
You've missed the opening php brackets (`<?php`) from the code listed above, but was that just a mistake?

Comment: What did you get as a result when you clicked button

Comment: I got the email field return ... I.e. 'Jeremy'

Comment: Is it possible that the server doesn't support PHP? If you go to the test_ajax.php file directly, what does it return? Should return... 
{"error":true,"msg":"You did not enter you email."}

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the opening of the php file and the declaration of $return as array. I tried this and it works fine:

```
<?
$return = array();
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you email.';
}
else {
    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['msg'] = 'You\'ve entered: ' . $_POST['email'] . '.';
}
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: any chance this could be a client side issue.  I have tried firefox, safari and ie

Comment: Not sure. I tested with FF3.6 and IE9.0, both works fine, returning `{"error":false,"msg":"You've entered: Jeremy."}`. You could check it using Firebug console.

Comment: Check by using the complete php opening tag `<?php`. Maybe your server doesn't allow the short one.

Comment: Sorry, your console should show the ajax call on process and the returning value if any, not sure where do you see data is undefined.